# Element 'LinkButton' is not a known element

Tags: asp.net, compiler-errors

using Visual Studio 2012 and I am receiving the following error when I try to include a link button in my gridview:

Element 'LinkButton' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing.

I have tried deleting the contents of the following folder but this has not worked:

AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ReflectedSchemas

```
     <asp:GridView ID="gvProjUpdates" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" >
            <Columns>           
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add

> **ItemTemplate**

within

> **TemplateField**

and add `LinkButton` Within that

like this

```
> <asp:GridView ID="gvProjUpdates" runat="server"
> AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4">
>     <Columns>
>         <asp:TemplateField>
>             <ItemTemplate>
>                 <asp:LinkButton runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
>             </ItemTemplate>
>         </asp:TemplateField>
>     </Columns> </asp:GridView>
```